# Why does this script give me gibberish? (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, import

This script is supposed to delete a file, and write 3 lines instead:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

filesource = "C:\Users\Miguel\Downloads\Python\%s" % filename

txt = open(filesource)

print filesource
print txt.read()

print "Let's delete the file"
raw_input("Delete? Use Ctrl+C to go back")

target = open(filesource, 'r+')
target.truncate(1)

print "Provide 3 lines for the file"

line1 = "aaaaaaa"
line2 = "bbbbbbb"
line3 = "ccccccc"

target.write (("%s\n%s\n%s\n") % (line1, line2, line3))

print target.read()

target.close()
```

However it gives me the three lines AND a lot of gibberish.

Little help please?

Comment: Why don't you use `w+` mode so it will truncate the file automatically when you open it?

Comment: Your file pointer `target` is at the *end* of the file when you attempt to read. You'll first have to rewind to the start, if you want to read the lines you wrote: `target.seek(0)` should do that.

Comment: @Evert Since he didn't rewind, why is he seeing anything when he calls `target.read()`?

Comment: @Barmar I  don't know: at a guess, since the file's not closed, there is no EOF marker, and Python/the underlying system will  just happily read past the current end of the file (since it's not defined).

Comment: I fixed it! I used w+ mode then truncated everything after that! Should I write this as an answer by the way?

Also, the gibberish is still generated, I'm only truncating it away. Why does it happen on first place?

Comment: I don't think that's right. It should be using Python's file buffer, not the actual file.

Comment: @MiguelAlberolaCano Why did you truncate? `w+` mode truncates automatically.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `truncate(1)` instead of `truncate(0)`? That leaves the first byte of the old file.

Comment: @MiguelAlberolaCano you ask why it produces gibberish, then state you fixed the problem, and mention it still produces gibberish. What then, is the actual problem you have?

Comment: @Evert That sounds likely. What function is it to close the file? I thought that target.close() would do the trick :S

Comment: @Evert I want to know where does the gibberish come from and how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar it's a guess; and it may depend on the OS.

Comment: You close the file *after* you read from its end, so that's not going to help. Better yet, use a context manager: `with open(filesource, 'w+') as target: ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `w+` mode instead of `r+` so the file will be truncated automatically when it's opened.

Then you'll need to rewind after you write, so you can read what was just written.

```
with open(filesource, 'w+') as target:
    print "Provide 3 lines for the file"

    line1 = "aaaaaaa"
    line2 = "bbbbbbb"
    line3 = "ccccccc"

    target.write (("%s\n%s\n%s\n") % (line1, line2, line3))
    target.seek(0)
    print target.read()
```

Comment: It worked! I'm confused about why not using target.seek(0) leads to gibberish but at least it doesn't require a truncation (or however that's called). Thanks! :)

Comment: `with target = open(filesource, 'w+'):` is new to me; is there a preferred style compared to `with open(filesource, 'w+') as target:`?

Comment: No, that was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

to delete the filesource use:
`import os`
`os.remove(filesource)`

you also open the filesource twise witiout closing it as txt and as target

edit (to just delete the contents of the file without deleting it):

```
target = open(filesource, 'w+')
print "Provide 3 lines for the file"

line1 = "aaaaaaa"
line2 = "bbbbbbb"
line3 = "ccccccc"

target.write (("%s\n%s\n%s\n") % (line1, line2, line3))
target.seek(0)
print target.read()
target.close()
```

Comment: These are comments, not an answer to the actual problem/question asked.

Comment: Thanks but I want to delete its contents, not the file itself :)

Comment: to delete a file contents just open it eith write attribute

Comment: @Evert i edited the answer to match the users question